# How to persist js console logs across page load in IE11

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, internet-explorer-11, console.log

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. Open the console (press F12).
2. Navigate or reload the page.
3. Observe the console.

**What is the expected result?**

There should be a way to keep the contents of the console around. It shouldn't be on by default, but it should be available.

**What happens instead?**

The console is always cleared.

> we can persist console log on Chrome and Firefox browser

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question. At best it's a bug report for IE11. Actually it's not even that, it's a feature request.

Comment: If you have question - please edit your post to include one. If you have feature request to IE team - make sure to start with https://connect.microsoft.com/IE .